# How to Add Prefix in WebView URL?

Tags: android, url, webview

I have a URL Field in my WebView, it works fine but i want it to add a prefix ("https://www.google.com/search?q=")                                                        in the url every time i press the search button

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private WebView webView;
private EditText urlEditText;
private ProgressBar progress;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

urlEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.urlField);
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebViewClient());


CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);//Enable Cookies
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);//Enable Java Script
webView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/"); //Set Home page
webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);//Remove ScrollBars
webView.getSettings().setDefaultFontSize(12);//Set Font Size
webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);//Enable Image Loading
webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);//Enable Flash
webView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);//Transparent Screen When Loading
  //webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);//Set Zoom Controls 

webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024*1024*8);//Set Cache (8mb)
String appCachePath =         getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();//Set Cache (8mb)
webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(appCachePath);//Set Cache (8mb)
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);//Set Cache (8mb)
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);//Set Cache (8mb)
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);//Set Cache (8mb)


 //////888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888   

progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
progress.setMax(100);

Button openUrl = (Button) findViewById(R.id.goButton);
openUrl.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String url = urlEditText.getText().toString();
        if (validateUrl(url)) {
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.loadUrl(url);

            MainActivity.this.progress.setProgress(0);
        }
    }

    private boolean validateUrl(String url) {
        return true;
    }
});

}

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebChromeClient {
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {         
    MainActivity.this.setValue(newProgress);
    super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
 }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
return true;
}

public void setValue(int progress) {
this.progress.setProgress(progress);       

/////88888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888
}
private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webview, String url)
{


webview.loadUrl(url);
return true;
}
}
@Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{

 if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack())

{
webView.goBack();
return true;
}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the onClick() method of the button, just concatenate url and the query.

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String url = urlEditText.getText().toString();
        String prefix = "https://www.google.com/search?q=";
        if(!url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://"))
        {
            url = prefix + url;
        }
        if(url.endsWith(".com") || url.endsWith(".as") || url.endsWith(".uk") || url.endsWith(".biz"))
        {
            if(!url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://"))
            {
                url = "http://" + url;
            }
        }
        if (validateUrl(url)) {
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.loadUrl(url);

            MainActivity.this.progress.setProgress(0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Lol. You're supposed to post problems not blatant questions :P
Hence you got a downvote for your question. Either way, agar dhanyawaad bolna hai to mark as correct kar dein :)

Comment: Lol. You want that if the search query entered in the EditText does not start from http:// or https://, then add the prefix to the query? Am I right?

Comment: Well that is what the code will do :)
Did you run it?

Comment: Could you elaborate in one go what you require? Just give examples for all scenarios.

Comment: But then, if there is no "http://" or "https://", in that case, we will be adding the google prefix right? This is why I asked for examples.
e.g. string entered "food" - result = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + food
Give me more such examples

Comment: I'll ask you one final time. Give me examples.

Comment: Well the suffix part can be checked but for some known strings. I can check for ".com", ".as", ".uk", ".biz" but I can't just check whether it ends in a domain or not. That would be complicated

Comment: Check the answer. I've done what I could. Goodnight :)
If you have any queries, I'll check tomorrow

Comment: andy bhai kuch to karoo :(

Comment: What is the error that you're getting? You should create a new question for it (after research though)

Comment: Which part are you referring to by second part?

Comment: Whatever you want to discuss, discuss it here. :)

Comment: kya yar ladkiyo ki tra shrmaa rhe ho

Comment: @Apk we discuss things here as it helps other who face similar problems. It isn't about shying or anything. :)

Answer (score 1):

Nothing could be easier:

Before

```
webview.loadUrl(url);
```

Add

```
url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + url;
```

Just keep in mind that the spaces must be replaced by a plus sign (+).

So, the url string will become:

```
url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + url.replace(" ", "+");
```

Comment: not working!! it is adding a prefix to my homepage!! NOT the Search!!

Comment: if you input "cats and dogs" in your search view (urlEditText) and url equals its contents, then you will get "https://www.google.com/search?q=cats and dogs". Just keep in mind that the spaces must be replaced by a plus sign (+). And so (see my edited answer), get "https://www.google.com/search?q=cats+and+dogs". Try clicking this link and you'll see it works. ;)

Comment: I'm sure. Or I'wouldn't say it

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I do it

```
String q = ((EditText)bar.findViewById(R.id.browser_searchbar)).getText().toString();
    if (q.contains(".")){
        if (q.startsWith("http://")||q.startsWith("https://"))
            WV.loadUrl(q);
        else if (q.startsWith("www."))
            WV.loadUrl("http://"+q);
        else
            WV.loadUrl("http://"+q);
    }
    else if (q.startsWith("about:")||q.startsWith("file:"))
        WV.loadUrl(q);
    else
        WV.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/#q="+q);
```